# Usage of printf() function in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, increment

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=1,y=1;
    for(;y&x<6;printf("%d %d\n",x,y++))
     x++;
}
```

Here I expected an output like:

```
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
6 5
```

but I got an output

```
2 1
```

Comment: `y&x<6` - the loop will only be executed once.

Comment: beware that `&` is bitwise binary and operator.  If you need to do boolean AND operator, it is `&&` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `<` has higher precedence than `&`from [here](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

So in the second iteration `y=2` and `x=1`. `x<6` becomes true - results in `1` which **when `AND`ed with `y`** the result becomes `0`. So it stops. `y<x&6` is equivalent to `y&(x<6)`.

To explain you how `AND` works :- (shown in 6 bits - but the logic holds same way for `sizeof(int)*8` `bits`).

```
      000010
  AND 000001
   ----------
      000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much all.. i got confused with the precedence and bitwise AND, logical AND..its clear now @coderredoc

Comment: @Aksh.: Glad it helped you and you appreciated that. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to check if both y and x are smaller than 6? 
if so, instead of `y&x<6` you should use `(y<6)&&(x<6)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x=1,y=1;
for(;y<6&x<6;printf("%d%d_",x,y++))
 x++;
}
```

try this

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    for(x = 1, y = 1; (y & x)<6;printf("%d %d\n",x,y++));
        x++;
    return 0;
}
```

because, as pointed by @coderredoc, `>` has higher precedence than `&`.